# Cast Mongoose Document to other similar Model

Tags: node.js, mongoose, mongoose-schema

So I have the following layout for my app:

1. UserSchema    (contains username and password)

   ```
   var UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
   firstName: String,
   lastName: String,
   email: String,
   username: String,
   password: String
   }, options);
   UserSchema.plugin(passportLocalMongoose);

   module.exports = mongoose.model("User", UserSchema);
   ```
2. StudentSchema (discriminator() on User) with additional fields

   ```
   var StudentSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
   indexNumber: String,
   courses: [{
       id: {
           type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
           ref: "Course"
       },
       entryDate: {
           type: Date, 
           default: Date.now
       }
   }]
   }, options);
   module.exports = User.discriminator("Student", StudentSchema);
   ```
3. TeacherSchema (discriminator() on User) with additional fields

   ```
   var TeacherSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
   degree: String,
   courses: [{
       type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
       ref: "Course"
   }]
   }, options);
   module.exports = User.discriminator("Teacher", TeacherSchema);
   ```

I am using passport local-strategy to User.register().

```
router.post("/register", function(req,res) {
var newUser = new User({
    firstName: req.body.firstName,
    lastName: req.body.lastName,
    email: req.body.email,
    username: req.body.username
});
User.register(newUser, req.body.password, function(err, user) {
    if(err) throw err;
    passport.authenticate("local")(req, res, function() {
        req.flash("success", "Welcome " + user.username + ".");
        res.redirect("/");
    });
});
});
```

Now all this is under same collection **users** in db (because of discriminators)

How do I, after an user registers, "promote" him to student or teacher, so I can have those additional fields in his object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting `__t` to "Teacher" or "Student" using an `update` command on the User model. I think the default discriminator key is `__t` so you need something like:

```
user.update({$set: {__t: "Student" } }, callback)`
```

Then you'll need to pull it with the Discriminator again to get your fields:

```
const Student = User.discriminator("Student", StudentSchema);
Student.findById(id, callback)
```